# How to get private ip address of client in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, ip

I want to know the private ip address of client who are interacting with my spring boot application. These clients are also the spring boot applications.  Some of them are running behind proxy.(for these clients I tried to get x-forwarded-for headers). I have tried to get ip address of them from the httpservletrequest but I am only able to get their public ip. (like one of client application is running on 192.12.34.5 server. But my application only able to get public ip like-152.12.3.56.) Is there any way to get private ip of client?

Comment: No, it is private (and local) for a reason.

Comment: You cannot get the private IP of client in server side. But you can get the IP of client machine in client app and pass it as a parameter to server.